# Joomla - How to create overrides for component files not in view

Tags: joomla, components

I am making changes to the JbusinessDirectory in joomla. 
I have added some extra fields to the contact form on the business listing using code changes in the companies view. But now I need to send these field inputs by email.

I am trying to add the values to the email template but I can't find a view that I can edit to do this. The files are located at htdocs/components/com_jbusinessdirectory/classes/services/EmailService.php
htdocs/components/com_jbusinessdirectory/assets/defines.php

How can I create an override for this?
I am not even sure these are the exact files I need to work with but they seem to contain the code that creates the email template.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please include some minimal code in your question. External links are not welcome here. Unless you link to github or other trustable sites. For guidance please check the [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page and [how to create a minimal example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Joomla supports overrides for views and layouts, if your alterations happens before they reach the view, or the component doesn't use layout, you have to do otherwise than override.